# What is rate of heat produced in terms of radius $r$ in viscous liquid under gravity?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, velocity, viscosity

> what is the dependency of the rate of heat produced in terms of radius $r$ after the drop attains terminal velocity when A small ball of radius $r$ is falling in a viscous liquid under gravity?

My efforts include:

The forces acting on the sphere are its weight $\dfrac 4 3πr^3ρg$ downwards, buoyancy force $\dfrac 4 3 \pi r^3\sigma g$ upwards, and viscous force $6π\eta rv$ upwards. The sphere attains the terminal velocity it when the resultant force on it is zero i.e.,$$\dfrac 4 3πr^3ρg=\dfrac43πr^3σg+6πηrvt$$

I don't know how to Solve the above equation to get the terminal

Comment: Hi Aakash Thoriya. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic okay

Comment: @Qmechanic guide me, how can I solve this question?

Comment: The heat generation is equal to the integral of the drag force integrated with respect to  the differential displacement.